powershell variable substitution doesn't work
Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I'm quite new in ps..
Running the curl this way works correctly (mailgun sends an email with attachment):
 curl -s --user 'api:***' `
   https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages `
   -F from='Builder <failed-tests@fff-software.com>' `
   -F to=eduard.dubilyer@fff-software.com `
   -F subject='Build failed!!!' `
   -F text='Your build has been failed.' -F attachment='1.txt'

Now trying to add a variable substirution:
 $attstr="-F attachment='1.txt'"
 curl -s --user 'api:***' `
   https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages `
   -F from='Builder <failed-tests@fff-software.com>' `
   -F to=eduard.dubilyer@fff-software.com `
   -F subject='Build failed!!!' `
   -F text='Your build has been failed.' $attstr

Looks like the variable is ignored (getting mail w/o attachment)

The command you're actually executing is:
curl -s --user api:*** `
    https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages
    ... etc... `
    -F text='Your build has been failed.' `
    "-F attachment='1.txt'"

Note the double quotes around -F attachment='1.txt' - I don't know how curl interprets that, but it's treating the variable contents as string data rather than as command arguments.
Splatting
If you want the individual parts of your string variable to be passed as separate arguments try splatting them as an array instead:
$cmdargs = @( "-F", "attachment='1.txt'" )

curl -s --user api:*** `
    https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages
    ... etc... `
    -F text='Your build has been failed.' `
    @cmdargs

which will execute:
curl -s --user api:*** `
    https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages
    ... etc... `
    -F text='Your build has been failed.' `
    -F attachment='1.txt'

without the surrounding quotes.
echoargs utility
A good way to diagnose these sorts of argument-parsing issues is use the echoargs.exe utility with the same arguments as your original command (e.g. curl ...) and see what it outputs to the console...
PS> $attstr="-F attachment='1.txt'"

PS> c:\src\so\echoargs.exe -s --user 'api:***' `
>>    https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages `
>>    -F from='Builder <failed-tests@fff-software.com>' `
>>    -F to=eduard.dubilyer@fff-software.com `
>>    -F subject='Build failed!!!' `
>>    -F text='Your build has been failed.' `
>>    $attstr
Arg 0 is <-s>
Arg 1 is <--user>
Arg 2 is <api:***>
Arg 3 is <https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages>
Arg 4 is <-F>
Arg 5 is <from=Builder <failed-tests@fff-software.com>>
Arg 6 is <-F>
Arg 7 is <to=eduard.dubilyer@fff-software.com>
Arg 8 is <-F>
Arg 9 is <subject=Build failed!!!>
Arg 10 is <-F>
Arg 11 is <text=Your build has been failed.>
Arg 12 is <-F attachment='1.txt'>

Command line:
"C:\src\so\echoargs.exe" -s --user api:*** https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/***.com/messages -F "from=Builder <failed-tests@fff-software.com>" -F to=eduard.dubilyer@fff-software.com -F "subject=Build failed!!!" -F "text=Your build has been failed." "-F attachment='1.txt'"

(scroll to the end of the line to see the double-quoted variable value).
You can download a pre-built echoargs.exe binary from various locations (make sure you trust the one you use), or the source is available to compile yourself (see this GitHub gist for one version https://gist.github.com/pohatu/80b2b01492b0a22e874e).

Additional info
My original answer suggested using curl ... $cmdargs instead of splatting with curl ... @cmdargs - @MathiasR.Jessen is correct to point out that explicitly splatting the variable is the preferred approach.
An additional comment by @mklement0 says

array-based splatting is implicitly applied when calling external programs

so curl ... $cmdargs is logically equivalent to curl ... @cmdargs when $cmdargs is an array, but to make the intent clearer it's probably best to stick to curl ... @cmdargs.

Wow. Echoargs... I tried to find something like that. Will play around and update

It's a very simple but effective utility. There's a compiled-on-the-fly gist I've used a few times to make sure I trust the exe I'm calling - see https://gist.github.com/pohatu/80b2b01492b0a22e874e - no affiliation, just prefer to see what I'm running :-). (note - it only seems to compile in Windows PowerShell, but the exe can be invoked fine from PowerShell (Core) 7.x)

And what if I need to build the args string dynamically? Can I add arguments one by one to this datastructure? For example I have an array of 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and I want to iterate through it and build @("-F", "attachment='1.txt'", "-F", "attachment='2.txt'", "-F", "attachment='1.txt'") ?

You can build the array dynamically: $cmdArgs = @(); if( $something ) { $cmdArgs += @("-F" , "attachment='1.txt'") } (although note the conventional wisdom that for performance reasons you should avoid the "assignment by addition" operator += to append to arrays).

works like a charm. Thanks a lot @mclayton. Accepting

@mclayton I think you want @cmdArgs here

@MathiasR.Jessen - possibly, but empirically, echoargs ... $cmdArgs seems to work as well here (gives the same output as echoargs ... @cmdargs in the command ^^^ at least). Not sure if $cmdargs and @cmdargs maybe just work the same for native commands with string array variables... (definitely work differently for hashtables though)

@MathiasR.Jessen - added an update to clarify

@mclayton Sorry, I wasn't clear in my previous message: when you're using $cmdArgs to pass an array of arguments, use @cmdArgs to have powershell pass them as separate string values

@MathiasR.Jessen - np. echoargs ... $cmdargs does appear to pass the values as separate arguments for the simple case of $cmdargs being an array of strings though (echoargs ... $cmdargs gives Arg 12 is <-F> Arg 13 is <attachment='1.txt'> and an unquoted -F attachment='1.txt' in the commandline), but you're right that splatting is probably more correct. I'll have a look at reworking the answer later today...

The Pscx module has not been updated for 6 1/2 years. Is it all good with PowerShell Core?

In other words: In your "vs" juxtaposition, the commands are identical, but only the first output looks correct.

@MathiasR.Jessen - I've reworked the answer to use explicit splatting - based on @mklement0's comment, curl ... $cmdaergs is equivalent to curl ... @cmdargs *for array-valued variables```, but explicitly splatting makes the intent much clearer - thanks for the suggestions :-)...

@mklement0 - I've edited the answer - I basically rushed the "update" section and bodged up - the comparison should have read something like $cmdargs = @{ "aaa" = "bbb" }; echoargs $cmdargs -> "echoargs.exe" System.Collections.Hashtable, but I've deleted that whole section now as it was dsuperfluous and distracting :-)...
